# Pacman downgrading my Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, upgrade, pacman, amd

While updating my Linux installation on an AMD Ryzen system with `sudo pacman -Syu`, I noticed this row:

```
gremlins/linux-zen    5.12.1.zen2-1     5.12.4.zen1-1      0.05 MiB      98.39 MiB
```

So the kernel would be updated from version 5.12.1.zen2-1 to 5.12.4.zen1-1.

Why the downgrade from zen2 to zen1?

My laptop has an AMD Ryzen 7 2700U, Zen 2, processor. The Linux distribution is Artix (Arch based).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a downgrade from `zen2` to `zen1`. It's an upgrade from `5.12.1.zen2-1` to `5.12.4.zen1-1`. You can't just split out a component in the middle of the version string to decide if its newer or older.

You're seeing the result of a double layer of versioning applied. Package versions generally (across distros) tend to comprise both the upstream version (`5.12.1-zen2` and `5.12.4-zen1` here) and a distro-specific version (here, both are `1`, the number after the last hyphen) intended to be used for distro-specific updates (e.g., custom patches applied, rebuilds made due to changes in build dependencies, etc.). The situation is complicated here by the Zen kernel itself being a downstream of Linux, so they tack on [their own version modifier](https://github.com/zen-kernel/zen-kernel/tags/) (`zen2`, `zen1`) after the real upstream (Linux kernel) version (`5.12.1`, `5.14.1`).

So imagine something like this:

1. Linus publishes a new kernel, say `x.y.z`
2. The Zen folks publish their new version based on that - `x.y.z-zen1`
3. Arch Linux publishes their packages based on *that* - `x.y.z-zen1-1`
4. Arch Linux publishes another package based on `x.y.z-zen1` because some dependency got changes (maybe a new version of `gcc` or something) - `x.y.z-zen1-2`
5. The Zen folks publish one more version base don the same Linux version, maybe tacking on another patch or something - `x.y.z-zen2`.
6. Arch Linux publishes that: `x.y.z-zen2-1` (note how the Arch Linux part of the number resets)
7. Linus publishes a new kernel `x.a.z`
8. When Zen publishes a new version based on `x.a.z`, now they will use `x.a.z-zen1`, since it's their first release based on `x.a.z`.

Comment: just for sake of completeness, `zen` is called **patchset**, and is applied to *vanilla* kernel; every new version of the patchset will increase its number: `zen1`, `zen2`, and so on...